# git verify commit signature visualization tool

Tags: git, bitbucket

I'm looking for any tool or suggestion how can I display git commit signatures (username and email) for a specific set of local history.

I know I can use the verify-commit for each commit hash using `git verify-commit <commit_hash>` but doing this for every commit is really time consuming.

I've recently started working with git and am using signed commits. I'm using Bitbucket and they're still *gathering interest* regarding this information [BSERV-9983](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BSERV-9983)

Since changing the information about the commit author locally is really easy I'm looking for a local tool that would show me this information easily. I was expecting this functionality with tools such as [tortoise git "show log"](https://tortoisegit.org/).

Could anyone explain why this kind of information isn't displayed in tools that visualize the "show log" information for or if I missed perhaps missed this information in one of the existing tools.

Comment: `Could anyone explain why this kind of information isn't displayed in tools` reason is simple, number of users who are signing every commit is so slim that this feature is not considered a high priority when tool is develop.

Comment: Check `git extension` I see [they did some task for signing a commit](https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions/pull/4390), but I'm not sure how information about signature is displayed in git log view.